# edit htaccess to get inside a folder for rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

After some help from another question i managed to figure out about .htaccess on my website for Friendly SEO links.

My public_html folder contains those files

- index.php
- .htaccess
- buisnessdetails.php
- eventDetails.php

My htaccess so far is this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\ (.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /eventDetails\.php\?id=(.+)&name=(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /eventDetails.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So when someone clicks an href which has `http://sourtouki.gr/123/abc`
the htaccess file goes to the 
`eventDetails.php` file.

But now i want it to change like this

i've edited my public_html folder like this

1. index.php
2. events(folder)
   2.1 eventDetails.php
3. buisness(folder)
   3.1 buisnessdetails.php

So with these changes i want to do the following thing
Changed the href link to 
`http://sourtouki.gr/events/123/abc`

What changes i must do to the `.htaccess` file so it can understand that if someone pushes the above link, to go to the `eventDetails.php` which is inside `events` folder??

And is it going to be editable so i can add also `buisness` folder inside that rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\ (.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /events/eventDetails\.php\?id=(.+)&name=(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /events/%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /events/eventDetails.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to update the rewrite destination of the last rule, it's fxd now. see the edit

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My link is `http://sourtouki.gr/events/123/abc`
and even with your last edited answer i'm getting a 404 error page.

Comment: where is the htaccess located?

Comment: sorry its my mistake. it was cached but when i entered with incognito mode, it was ok. One last question. If i want it to be the same rewrite rules about `buisness` folder within `buisnessdetails.php` what is the proper way to write it down in the htaccess?? I guess its the same exact code

Comment: Yes, you can write same exact code for your **/business** or any other similar uris .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115580/discussion-between-kwnstantinos-natsios-and-starkeen).

Comment: could you help me with this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328110/rewrite-url-condition-for-subfolder