# rewrite url condition for subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an htaccess file here

`/en/.htaccess`

and i would like to make this condition (which is for the main htacces inside public_html) to work also for the subfolder `en`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /events/eventDetails\.php\?id=(.+)&name=(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /events/%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /events/eventDetails.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

my htaccess starts like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteRule    ^hot-events/?$    hot-events.php    [NC,L]
```

The last line translates the link correctly as www.example.com/hot-events

But i also want it to make the first condition work.
I mean when someone uses this link
`https://example.com/en/events/123/abc` 
it should run the query by this file

```
https://example.com/en/events/eventDetails.php?id=123&name=abc
```

Directory Structure

```
   root/
   ├── .htaccess
   ├── index.php
   ├── events/
   │     └── eventDetails.php
   └── en/
        ├── .htaccess
        ├── index.php
        └── events/
                └── eventDetails.php
```

Comment: Is `/events/` an existent directory ?

Comment: @starkeen yes it is!

Comment: But why is **/events/** not in this url

https://example.com/en/eventDetails.php?id=123&name=abc ?

Comment: @starkeen sorry misstype, corrected the question!

Comment: What happens when you type

https://example.com/en/events/eventDetails.php?id=123&name=abc in in your browser's address bar? does it redirect the url to an incorrect path ?

Comment: it redirects me to example.com/events/123/abc. 
Something i have setted at the public html folder. @starkeen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117089/discussion-between-kwnstantinos-natsios-and-starkeen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your rewrite destination is incorrect. You are rewriting to `/events/eventDetails.php` instead of `/en/events/eventDetails.php` , try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteRule    ^hot-events/?$    hot-events.php    [NC,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /en/events/eventDetails\.php\?id=([^&]+)&name=(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en/events/%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /en/events/eventDetails.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: i pasted your code but it still redirects me to the main folder and not to the `/en/` folder

Comment: i think it has something to do with the htaccess of the main public html

Comment: Im so sorry but when i try to go at `example.com/en/eventDetails.php?id=123&name=abc` it loads the correct link !

Comment: That means /eventsDetails.php is not inside **/events/** folder?

Comment: Can you please post the structure of your directories?

Comment: Thanks, but /events/ folder is not there.

Comment: updated the question with the complete folder structure. i guess its the last time i forgot it sorry :(

Comment: Sorry, /events/ folder is inside /root or /en?

Comment: i updated the folder structure with a more detailed version. All i want to do is the `.htaccess` of the folder `en` to make a request of this link

`https://example.com/en/events/123/abc`

to run the query 

`https://example.com/en/events/eventDetails.php?id=123&name=abc`